# How to install GnuPG on Debian/Kali Linux?

Tags: linux, debian, gnupg, kali-linux

I would like to know how to install GnuPG on Debian (this case it's Kali). I understand you have to compile it, I can't find a pre-compiled version anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

GnuPG is preinstalled on Debian (and to assume, all its descendant releases). GnuPG is a very important part of the operating system, as it is used to verify the repository lists and package sources.

It should already be available as `gpg` (GnuPG 1, "classic" release) or `gpg2` (GnuPG 2.0 or 2.1, "stable" or "modern" releases). If you only have one of those, and want to install the other, they packages are named `gnupg` and `gnupg2`. If you do not see them, you might have to run `apt-get update` before.